# How to get duplicate rows with group by and order by?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the duplicate rows with order by, i'm trying in this way:

```
SELECT utc_id, utc_utiid, utc_comid, utc_recomendacoes FROM
( SELECT * FROM utilizador_competencia ORDER BY utc_recomendacoes DESC)
as sub GROUP BY utc_utiid, utc_comid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

The result:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
| utc_id | utc_utiid | utc_comid | utc_recomendacoes |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|     14 |         2 |       397 |                54 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Here the duplications rows but I want to get the utc_id -> 207 instead utc_ic -> 14:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
| utc_id | utc_utiid | utc_comid | utc_recomendacoes |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|     14 |         2 |       397 |                54 |
|    207 |         2 |       397 |                87 |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: You can't use an ORDER BY inside a subquery. You'll have to use it outside.

Comment: I don't think you can have an ORDER BY in your subquery. Plus ORDER BY doesn't do anything to eliminate duplicates. You can probably just remove the ORDER BY completely to get what you're after. But I don't know that this subquery is needed anyway.  What error does this query throw?

Comment: What does this mean:  "I want to get the duplicate rows with order by, i'm trying in this way"?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I already update the question.

Comment: Why do you prefer 207 instead of 14?  Perhaps you want `MAX()`?  See the added tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to guess that you intend:

```
select c.*
from utilizador_competencia c
where exists (select 1
              from utilizador_competencia c2
              where c2.utc_utiid = c.utc_utiid and
                    c2.utc_comid = c.utc_comid and
                    c2.utc_id <> c.utc_id
             )
order by c.utc_id, c.utc_id, c.utc_recomendacoes desc;
```

Comment: This gives you all copies?  Not just the 'last' one?

Answer (score 0):

an order by is applied on a visibile result  ..  a subquery  is only a data set  ..  so the order by for a subquery is unuseful
move the order by out the subquery

```
SELECT utc_id, utc_utiid, utc_comid, utc_recomendacoes 
FROM ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM utilizador_competencia 
    ) as sub 
GROUP BY utc_utiid, utc_comid  
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY utc_recomendacoes DESC
```

and based on your comment

```
SELECT utc_id, utc_utiid, utc_comid, utc_recomendacoes 
FROM utilizador_competencia 
GROUP BY utc_utiid, utc_comid  
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY utc_recomendacoes DESC
```

Comment: Hmm.. I want to get the duplicate row with "utc_recomendacoes DESC". That is select the duplicate row with DESC or ASC before group by.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.utc_id, t.utc_utiid, t.utc_comid, t.utc_recomendacoes
FROM
( SELECT utc_utiid, utc_comid 
  FROM utilizador_competencia 
  GROUP BY utc_utiid, utc_comid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) d
INNER JOIN utilizador_competencia t
ON d.utc_utiid=t.utc_utiid
AND d.utc_comid=t.utc_comid 
ORDER BY t.utc_recomendacoes DESC;
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: No, please take a look for the update of question, thanks.